# Why used App::uses('Controller', 'Controller') before all controllers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

Sorry to Ask but I can't understand why following line written before every controller.

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
```

If we write following code with extends `controller` that means all the property and function of `Controller` class we can access in `AppController`.

```
class AppController extends Controller{...}
```

So, My question is If I do not write `App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');` that have any effect in my code or perfomance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of App::uses('AppController', 'Controller') in each controller - cakephp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229431/what-is-the-purpose-of-appusesappcontroller-controller-in-each-controll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App::uses is a static method to register the location of a file (that corresponds with a class) to load for the PHP autoloader to be able to load it on-the-fly.

That `App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');` line declares that if the `AppController` `class` is referenced (or extended, in this case) and the `AppController class` isn't yet defined, that it should look for the file within the app/Controller directory and construct the actual filename like so: AppController.php Part of that is cakePHP convention, part PHP5.

The reason nothing breaks when you remove this line is because that file is probably required somewhere else in the application (another controller, during bootstrap-- so php already has the AppController class in memory.

The reason it's included on the first line is because the controller you baked extends the AppController class. It has a hard dependency on the AppController class being loaded and perhaps in the cake shell or unit testing environments the app controller isn't automatically loaded before hand so the inclusion must occur. App::uses is like telling cake (and PHP) that 'hey, if you're looking for the AppController class and you don't already have it, you should look in app/Controller directory and just add .php on the end!' If the file has already been loaded, App::uses would have no effect.

See [What is the purpose of App::uses('AppController', 'Controller') in each controller - cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25229699/2460470)

Comment: Please use comments and links instead of duplicating existing answers.